# assigning focus to an active element based on its id

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

The issue I am having is that I want to assign focus onto the current element that has the class "active", only one span element can hold this class at a time, and will be focused upon modal closing. Currently the method I have focuses, but only on the last one in the stack.

jQuery:

```
 $("#ConfirmationChangeTabModal").modal("hide");
 $('.active').find('#InstitutionInfoBtn').focus();
 $('.active').find('#DurationBtn').focus();
 $('.active').find('#POCList').focus();
```

Html:

```
   <span class="Subtab InstitutionDetailTab">
                            <span id="InstitutionInfoBtn" class="subTabAction">Details</span>
                            <span id="DurationBtn" class="subTabAction">Duration</span>
                            <span id="POCList" class="subTabAction">Points of Contact</span>
</span>
```

What I need to  be able to do is to focus based on the tab with the class, and its matching Id. The "active" class is being generated dynamically on click.

Comment: Is there a common pattern so you do not need to use an id. Something like  `$(".active div.tab").focus();` instead of having multiple checks?

Comment: @epascarello I will look and see if  that will work, because that was my initial thought as well, but it would not set focus on closing modal

Comment: @epascarello To clarify, there are several sets of tabs that have the same values, and also have active. This is the lowest most stack, and that is why I am using this particular method, so I can assign directly by id.

Comment: So can't you limit it further to a parent id of active? Just trying to simplify your code to one. And not sure why only the last one works. If you manually call the code will it focus the element? Maybe it is another issue...

Comment: @epascarello If I understand you correctly, I would limit this by selecting the parent id, and only executing this code within that parent-child set?

Comment: Logically, only one thing can have focus. So of course the last thing gets the focus.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan If I wanted to target the others, and didn't want to use a large if-else if stack. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do; there's no logic as to which one of the three elements in your code should have the focus... Provide a [mcve] and I could try to help.